# Centos5: Custom comps.xml documentation/options?

Tags: yum, rpm, centos-5

I've got an app that I've packaged into rpms along with some of its dependencies.

I'd like to be able to have it accessible as a group for easy install/uninstall.

However, there's not too many things that I've found while googling that give a good overview of what the available options for a custom comps.xml would be (e.g. what are the attributes that can be added to the < packagereq > tag?; what other tags are allowed under the groups tag? etc.)

The specific issue I'm having is it's pulling in prior versions of packages from different repositories and trying to resolve dependencies for those packages (which I don't want). Is there an option to tell it to just pull the most recent version of each package?

Is there more documentation somewhere out there that I'm missing?